# Can input element in a form be style in such a way as to show % sign in the input box after the input?

Tags: html, css, mozilla

Is there a way to show a quantifier in HTML input field after whatever user had entered?

For example, I want a field to enter percentage, such as 80%
But I want the user to only enter `80` into the input box, and I want the % sign to display after the number, but not actually be part of the input.  When form is submitted, I want only the number to be submitted and not a percent sign.

Can this be done?

Aside from the % sign, can this be done with other quantities, in the general case, such as say 50Hz, where user is expected to only enter `50`, and the Hz will be the quantifier visible after the input.

Note:

I am hoping for a pure-CSS or another "decorative-only" approach and in that regard, do not quite know how to approach the issue. My hope is not to have to enter the quantifier.  For example, if my quantifier is `Hz`, I don't want the user to type "50 Hz", I just want them to type "50", and see that it says Hz after it.  I could create a background image that has the % sign at the furthers-right end. Another solution is to use label, i.e. Percent (%), and let the user enter just the number without % sign.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

Check if $ has been added already, if not then append!

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933164/add-suffix-to-form-field)

```js
$("#test").on("keydown", function(event) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var bool = event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey || event.keyCode == 8;
  if (!bool) {
    if (val.indexOf('$') == -1) {
      $(this).val(val + '$');
      this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = $(this).val().length - 1;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Comment: This can give you results like 5$0 if you type slowly. Also it won't allow you to delete past the $, if you wish to go back and edit it.

Comment: @RobertWade This is better than the old code, can you please check!

Comment: I get a multiple errors saying `ReferenceError: event is not defined` ...

Comment: @Dennis add event argument to the function, can you replicate the issue and share? check my updated answer!

Comment: Much better.  OP did say he wanted to make sure the quantifier doesn't submit with the form, so you could add a submit handler if you'd want.. however OP didn't really show any effort to do this on his own, so....

Comment: I was originally hoping for a pure-CSS or another "decorative-only" approach and did not know how to approach the issue at all. I can strip the % sign using back-end PHP, without using JavaScript, so that's not the issue. I can even allow the user to enter the % sign themselves and strip it later, or accept both inputs with or without the %.  Another approach is perhaps create a background image that has the % sign at the furthers-right end, removing the need to type or strip % sign.  Another solution is to use label, i.e. `Percent (%)`, and let the user enter just the number without % sign

Comment: @Dennis You have stated like almost all the possible solutions, CSS fix is the easiest in my opinion, if not then please use this code as reference and you can get the % with either PHP or javascript!